# Как решить повтор события change в FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, .net

Мониторинг файла. При изменениях в файле почему-то дважды запускается `Change`. Как можно это решить?

Вот код:

```
public void monitoring(string path)
{
    this.sPath = path;
    string first = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string second = Path.GetFileName(path);
    FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(first, second);
    fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

public void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Be happy :3");
    SplitAndQuery(this.sPath);
}
```

Comment: А вы не исключаете, что событие таки случилось дважды? Например, файл удалён и снова создан? Попробуйте залогировать `е.ChangeType`.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Дело в том, что `FileSystemWatcher` опирается на уведомления от ОС. А запись изменений в файл далеко не всегда может являться атомарным действием: например, notepad.exe пишет на диск в несколько приемов, отдельно файл и отдельно его атрибуты, что повлечет за собой несколько срабатываний события `Changed`. Или при копировании/перемещении файлов запись происходит в несколько приемов.

Избавиться от этого можно попробовать разными способами. Самый железобетонный, но не всегда подходящий -- отключать генерацию событий. Но пользоваться им надо аккуратно, т.к. можно пропустить другие полезные изменения.

```
public void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Be happy :3");
        SplitAndQuery(this.sPath);
    }
    finally
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

Другой подход -- опираться на дату последней модификации файла (опционально еще и на `e.ChangeType`):

```
DateTime lastWriteTime = DateTime.MinValue;

public void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime writeTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(this.sPath);
    if (lastWriteTime != writeTime)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Be happy :3");
        SplitAndQuery(this.sPath);
        lastWriteTime = writeTime;
    }
}
```

Если файл изменяется не очень часто, а события приходят одно за другим, то можно использовать таймер с некоторым ожиданием и отсекать события, для которых не прошло нужное количество времени.

В общем, выбор решения целиков зависит от ваших требований (впрочем, как обычно :)).

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло

Comment: @YoFi не за что!

Answer (score 1):

Никак, просто имейте в виду, что событие срабатывает дважды. Это нормально для `FileSystemWatcher`.

Конкретные решения придётся принимать по ситуации. Я обычно держу в классах информацию, которая мне помогает понять, надо обрабатывать текущее событие `changed` или нет - последнее время изменения, текущее местоположение файла, наличие файла и т.д.

Comment: далеко не всегда событий 2, у меня для одного экземпляра прилетает **5** событий для другого **3**

Answer (score 1):

Решение со счетчиком опасно, т.к. игнорирует возможные другие изменения.

Есть вариант с отложенным исполнением, когда пропускаются изменения только в момент ожидания.

```
private FileSystemWatcher _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

public void Start() 
{
    ....
    _watcher.Changed += _watcher_Changed;
    _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void _watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(ReloadData).Start(); // запускаем в отдельном потоке, для отсечения очереди событий при многоэтапной записи в файл
}

private void ReloadData()
{ 
    // блокируем выполнение для пропуска нескольких этапов записи файла
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(_watcher))
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000); // ждём 3 сек пока файл сохраняется
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_watcher);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return; // все остальные входы в течении 3 секунд будут игнорироваться
    }
    // через 3 секунды происходит реакция
    Execute();
}
```

Comment: Не надо плодить столько потоков. Решение с отложенной обработкой можно сделать гораздо лучше.

Comment: Так какое именно решение?

Comment: Запустить таймер на 3 секунды и игнорировать события, которые происходят в эти 3 секунды. При желании можно так же сбрасывать таймер, чтобы отсчёт 3 секунд начинался заново.

Comment: в целом да, будет компактнее, но таймер это тоже поток...

Comment: Во-первых, системный таймер - это не поток. Он при возникновении события просто кинет сообщение в очередь. Во-вторых, если бы он даже был потоком, он был бы одним потоком. А в приведённом варианте на каждое событие создаётся новый поток. Т. е. если в течение 3 секунд произойдёт 10 событий, то будет 10 потоков, а не 1.

Comment: кстати создание потока без создания на него постоянной ссылки (new Thread(ReloadData).Start();) оказывается опасно, т.к. при длительном ожидании поток может быть просто убит сборщиком мусора (возникало ожидание на 30 сек из-за выключенной БД), думаю с таймером будет та же история, нужно обязательно хранить ссылку в поле класса

Comment: по количеству потоков согласен, уже сам на таймер переделал, из-за выше указанной причины

Comment: Нет. Поток сам является корнем и не может быть убит сборщиком. Таймер тоже вряд ли кто-то убьёт.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение которое мне подходит, но не факт что подойдет всем:

```
public void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            changeCount++;
            if (changeCount == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Be happy :3");
                SplitAndQuery(this.sPath);
            }
            else
            {
                changeCount = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Be very happy, its works");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Пропускать каждый второй - это не очень хорошо.

Comment: далеко не всегда событий 2, у меня для одного экземпляра прилетает 5 событий для другого 3